# Is it possible to install a PWA on windows via script?

Tags: windows, installation, progressive-web-apps

We are currently in the process of planing to replace one of our old Winforms applications and are unsure which technologie we should use. Currently, we are looking into deployment of different technologies, which poses the question: Is it possible to install a PWA via comand line / powershell script, or any other way that does not involve opening the browser and doing it manually?

The application need to be installed on about 200 computer, without any help of intune or other management apps for various reasons.

While we are currently leaning towards an Angular / PWA application, this is a big hurdle that needs to be clarified before we can make our final decision.